# How to overwrite Javascript / Typescript Set iterator or values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, data-structures, set

I need to do a set of Arrays. Javascript's default Set does not work with arrays, so I added this new Typescript class:

```js
export class ArraySet extends Set<any> {
  override add(arr: any): any {
    super.add(arr.toString());
  }
  override has(arr): boolean {
    return super.has(arr.toString());
  }
}
```

is there a way to edit this class in order to get values as array??

Currently:

```
const set = new ArraySet()
set.add([1,1])
set.add([2,1])
set.forEach(e => console.log(typeof(e)))
# string 
# string
```

Expected:

```
const set = new ArraySet()
set.add([1,1])
set.add([2,1])
set.forEach(e => console.log(typeof(e)))
# object       # because I want the element to be the array 
# object
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator

Comment: What's the use case? Why do you want a set? Why not just use an array of arrays and iterate that? https://tsplay.dev/WYZgbw

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848078/how-to-overwrite-javascript-typescript-set-iterator-or-values#comment130398262_73848078) If it's about managing your own definition of object identity, then you'll need to implement the other methods as well, and you might as well just create a "JSONSet" class that uses `JSON.stringify` to serialize and `JSON.parse` to deserialize at the interfaces. But keep in mind that this custom set still won't store or return the real values that you're providing: just "equivalent" representations.

Comment: Try `class NumberArraySet extends Map<string, number[]>`, and store the real array values in the value part for each key-value pair.

Comment: I needed to generate random vectors without repeating items, that's why I was using a set.

Answer (score 1):

combining a few of the suggestions you could maybe get away with not needing to override the iterator part and simply controlling what goes inside the set like so

```
class ArrayNumberSet extends Set<number[]> {
  private readonly keyMap: Map<string, number[]> = new Map();

  private key(value: number[]): string {
    return JSON.stringify(value);// or value.toString()
  }

  override add(value: number[]): this {
    const key = this.key(value);
    const old = this.keyMap.get(key);
    if (old) {
      this.delete(old);
    }
    this.keyMap.set(key, value);
    super.add(value);
    return this;
  }

  override clear(): void {
    this.keyMap.clear();
    super.clear();
  }

  override delete(value: number[]): boolean {
    const key = this.key(value);
    const old = this.keyMap.get(key);
    if (old) {
      this.keyMap.delete(key);
      return super.delete(old);
    }
    return false
  }

  override has(value: number[]): boolean {
      return this.keyMap.has(this.key(value))
  }
}
```

this would treat `[1, 2]`, `[2, 1]`, `[2, 1, 1]` as different objects. If you don't want that, consider a set of sets maybe or build a key from sorted arrays